# Queue::push Unable to find Class

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, octobercms

- Laravel Version: 5.1.46 (LTS)
- PHP Version: PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )

#### Description:

Using `Queue::push` is causing me some headaches on my production server:

```
$data = [
    'server' => $server,
    'week' => '201427'
];

Queue::push('\Cleanse\MyPluginName\Classes\Jobs\MyQueueClass', $data);
```

> exception 'ReflectionException'
>   with message 'Class \Cleanse\MyPluginName\Classes\Jobs\MyQueueClass does not exist'
>   in /october/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:741

It works fine on my local Mac server I develop on, but after uploading to my live server, I am getting the error above.

I have also tried using a closure, but I get:

```
Queue::push(function($job) use ($data) {
    $crawl = new RankingsUpdate();
    $crawl->updateWeek($data);

    $job->delete();
});
```

> [2017-05-30 02:41:33] production.ERROR: 
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: 
>   Class 'Cleanse\MyPluginName\Classes\CategoryDir\CategoryClass' not found in 
>   /var/www/html/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/SerializableClosure.php(210) : eval()'d code:8

Could it be a PHP version issue? It works on my MB Air, which is running PHP 7.0.11 (cli) (built: Sep 23 2016 20:33:19) ( NTS )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pitfall, make sure your folder names are lower case. Some operating systems are case sensitive.

For example the class `\Cleanse\MyPluginName\Classes\Jobs\MyQueueClass` should be stored in a file called `plugins/cleanse/mypluginname/classes/jobs/MyQueueClass.php`.